# Liquibase configuration in Gradle conventions plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, liquibase

I have a multi module Java / Gradle project where each module has identical configuration, so I would like to move that to a [convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) as a [pre-compiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins). The problem is that all of the modules use the [liquibase-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin), which seems non-trivial to implement.

First, the liquibase plugin implements its own dependency scope `liquibaseRuntime`, but my plugin does not know that scope. Here's my dependencies block (using a version catalog):

```
dependencies {
    implementation libs.plugins.jooq.liquibase
    implementation libs.plugins.gradle.liquibase

    liquibaseRuntime libs.postgresql
    liquibaseRuntime libs.liquibase
    liquibaseRuntime libs.jooq
    liquibaseRuntime libs.picocli
}
```

but that generates the error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method liquibaseRuntime() for arguments [map(valueof(DependencyValueSource))] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMissingMethodExecutionFailed.<init>(AbstractDynamicObject.java:190)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:184)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:80)
```

If I change `liquibaseRuntime` to `implementation` the error goes away, but I don't want to export these dependencies, they're just for the liquibase plugin.

Second, the actual plugin configuration requires a configuration closure like this:

```
liquibase{
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile "src/main/liquibase/changelog.xml"
            // more config
        }
    }
}
```

If I write this in my plugin, I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException:
Could not find method liquibase() for arguments [precompiled_EsrJooqLiquibase$_run_closure3@664b65b8] on project ':moduleA' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

How can I programmatically create such a configuration closure from the outside?

**Update**

The accepted answer works nicely, with one caveat:
to get the `liquibaseRuntime` scope to work, I had to register it myself, the way the gradle liquibase plugin does:

```
project.configure(project) {
    configurations.maybeCreate("liquibaseRuntime")
}
dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime(libs.postgresql) // etc
}
```

Comment: It should not be necessary to re-register `liquibaseRuntime` again; this happens when the plugin code runs. I suspect there is something non-standard in your setup... are you using `buildSrc/src/main/groovy` for your plugin code? With the `groovy-gradle-plugin` plugin applied in the `buildSrc` build script? And applying all plugins in the `plugins` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use external plugins in a pre-compiled script plugin, you need to add the JARs containing those plugins to the classpath of the plugin in the plugin's build script, much like for normal code ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins_precompiled.html#sec:applying_external_plugins)).

If you are writing the plugins in `buildSrc`, this would be in the file `buildSrc/build.gradle`.

The Maven coordinates<sup>1</sup> of the plugin JAR are used for this purpose, as for a regular library. These should be added to the `implementation` configuration:

```
// buildSrc/build.gradle

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.2.1'
}
```

We have also registered the Gradle Plugin Portal as a repository so Gradle knows where to find the JAR, since this plugin is available there.

Now you can apply the plugin in your pre-compiled script plugin and you should have access to all the usual configuration options:

```
// Precompiled script plugin code

plugins {
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle'
}
```

The plugin version is not necessary here since the plugin code is already on the classpath by virtue of the previous setup.

---

<sup>1</sup> The [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#maven-coordinates) (ie, the groupId:artifactId:version) are different to the plugin id (the latter being the identifier used to apply a plugin in Gradle). The Maven coordinates of a plugin published at the Gradle Plugin Portal are declared on the plugin's page (eg for [Liquibase](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.liquibase.gradle)) as the coordinates used for 'legacy plugin application'.

Comment: Works nicely, thanks. I wasn't aware of the distinction between buildSrc/build.gradle and the actual plugin, thanks.